# WkwebView - bottom part of the page is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am rendering website using WkWebView. The problem I am facing is that as shown in the screenshot, if I scroll to the bottom, part of the page (last 2 rows) is not visible. If I drag scrollbar to the bottom, it shows that part of the page and automatically scrolls upwards and that part becomes no longer visible to the user. Do I need to update my webview constraints or change the height of the webview?

Here is the screenshot

[image]

here is the code snapshot

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

let customFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: self.webViewContainer.frame.size.height))
     
self.webView = WKWebView (frame: customFrame , configuration: webConfiguration)
       webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
    
    
addConstraints(to: webView, with: webViewContainer)

func addConstraints(to webView: UIView, with superView: UIView) {
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    superView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your bottomConstraint is probably wrong, then.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this happening before.
I'd recommend

```
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Webpage is supposed to find out the viewport area and set its width and height  using CSS or JS.

Most UI frameworks have support for this by default

So when you scroll the scrolling happens within the webpage rather scrolling in the native view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is already set to false. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What's your superview ? Tableviewcell's contentview ?